# JSON show actual data based on IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> http://jsfiddle.net/Zyjwb/5/

How can I display actual names of **owners**, based on the specified **id**, inside infowindow for each **house/condo**?

So, If a **house** element has `1` and `3` listed inside **owners** attribute - turn them into `Jim` and `Peter` when **infowindow** is opened for each marker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure you are using to store the owners makes it very difficult to accomplish this.

```
var owners = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Jim'},
{
    id: '3',
    name: 'Peter'},
{
    id: '54',
    name: 'Harry'}];
```

If it was changed to the following, it would be as easy as `owners[elem.owner]`

```
var owners = {
    '1': 'Jim',
    '3': 'Peter',
    '54': 'Harry'
}
```

The current structure would require looping through the array to find an object that had the specified id.

**Update** Working demo(based on comments): http://jsfiddle.net/Zyjwb/12/

Comment: But, what if the **owners** array would also contain, let's say, a phone number of the person?

Comment: I don't think you can find object values that way.... http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Zyjwb/4/

Comment: @Blazemonger What are you referring to? `owners[elem.owner]`? http://jsfiddle.net/T5Yk9/

Comment: @Bob Then replace 'Jim' with a nested object.

Comment: Yes, it's not going to be as simple as owners[elem.owner] since elem.owner is an array

Comment: @Blazemonger: But, then how would I access the actual **name** or **phone**?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't construct the owners object correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Zyjwb/6/ works fine.

Comment: Here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyjwb/8/ it only returns one owner for each at the moment, but that could easily be abstracted into a function that returns multiple owners, or a phone number,etc all based on the passed in owner id.

Comment: @Bob instead of storing the owner's name as a string, store an object that contains the owner's name and phone number.

Comment: @Bob like this:      `content += '<h3>Owners:</h3>' + owners2[elem.owner]['name'];` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Zyjwb/9/

Comment: This is more along the lines of what i was looking at: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyjwb/12/

Comment: @Kevin B: So, If I wanted to include some different piece of information that would have same structure as owners, but of different context - I would need to make function for that too?

Comment: You dont "have" to make it a function, it is just easier to maintain that way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the owner info first:

above: `var content = '<div id="info">';`, add:

```
var ownerInfo = '';
var ownerList =  elem.owner;
for(var ow=0;ow<ownerList.length;ow++) {
            ownerInfo += "&bull; " + owners[ow].name +"<br />";
}
```

Then lower in your code:

```
content += '<h3>Owners:</h3>' + ownerInfo;
```